# Allow .JSON file type for HTML5 output on SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

How do i proceed in requesting a .JSON file to be unblocked from web application on SPO.

we are aiming to do is host and share content (interactive videos, 360 images etc) which we create in different software such as adobe, camtasia that are in HTML5.